# How to identify a deleted remote branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

How to know that a remote branch has been deleted in server side in Git?

I worked with my colleague on one UserStory. We created a branch for it (let's say `US_123`). After all these work was finished, my colleague merged the `US_123` into master branch and deleted (with `git push origin --delete US_123`).

For me, except for communication with my colleague, is there some way to know that `US_123` has been deleted at server side.

I have fetched the code from server with:

```
  git fetch
  git pull
```

But the remote branch `origin/US_123` (and local tracking branch `US_123`') is still listed in my side.

```
git fetch
git pull
git branch -vv
  US_123 9aee544 [origin/US_123] Merge branch 'US_123'
* master 9aee544 [origin/master] Merge branch 'US_123'
```

**Expected:**
The remote branch is marked as deleted. Like in TFS, the branch will become 'gray' means that relevant remote branch is deleted in TFS by someone.

**Actual:**
There is noting happened. At least, no any thing told me that the `US_123` has been deleted at server side.

```
W:\Git_Proj>git branch -vv
  US_123 9aee544 [origin/US_123] Merge branch 'US_123'
* master 9aee544 [origin/master] Merge branch 'US_123'
```

Comment: `git remote prune origin --dry-run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways to do that with git.

I tend to use `fetch` (`origin` being assumed here)

```
git fetch -p --dry-run
```

where [`-p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune) stands for "prune" and asks git to prune obsolete remote-tracking branches with the fetch

And also, as already offered by Alexan in his comment, you can do

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

Both (since they use [`--dry-run`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---dry-run)) will output the list of branches which *would be* removed if you had typed the same commands but without `--dry-run`